# Can anybody explain me this code

Tags: algorithm

```
// Dynamic Programming
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        int val = 12;
        int[] table = new int[val+1];
        table[0] = 0;

        for ( int i=1; i<=val; i++){
            int maxsqrt = (int) Math.Sqrt(i);
            int localmin = i;
            for (int j=1; j<=maxsqrt; j++){
                if ( table[i-j*j] < localmin) {
                    localmin = table[i-j*j];
                }
            }
            table[i] = localmin + 1;
    }

        Console.WriteLine("Min Val:"+ table[val]);
    }
}
```

I found this solution online for the following problem:

Given a number "n", find the least number of perfect square numbers sum needed to get "n"

Example: 
n=12, return 3 (4 + 4 + 4) = (2^2 + 2^2 + 2^2) NOT (3^2 + 1 + 1 + 1) 
n = 6, return 3 (4 + 1 + 1) = (2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2)

I am not able to understand the code.

Comment: Where exactly did you stuck? What line is unclear to you?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I am not able to understand the functionality of the inner j loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another easier way to solve the problem:

```
import java.util.*;

class Program2{
    int[] min;

    Program2(){
        min = new int[13];
        Arrays.fill(min, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    public void findMin(int n){
        min[0] = 0;
        for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
            for(int j=1 ; j*j<=i ; j++){
                min[i] = Math.min(min[i], min[i - j*j] + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Program2 obj = new Program2();

        obj.findMin(12);
        System.out.println("Min Value: " + obj.min[12]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an efficient implementation of the recursive solution:

```
f(x) = min{ f(x-1^2), f(x-2^2) , ..., f(x-floor(sqrt(x))^2) } + 1
```

Which is basically a brute force solution to the problem